# options.domAPI is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vuetify.js

I've tried adding stylus config of Vuetify to modify the global variables, until I noticed that it's not supported anymore.

I've run this command to install the required loaders: `npm i --save-dev stylus stylus-loader css-loader style-loader`.

After that, I started getting the error in the title, and after removing those libraries, it didn't remove it at all. I've tried running `npm reinstall` and have a complete fresh install of the npm packages.

My config is like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.31",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "stylus": "^0.55.0",
    "stylus-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
},
"dependencies": {
    "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.8",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
}
```

Error log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: options.domAPI is not a function
at addStyle (app.js:38836)
at modulesToDom (app.js:38824)
at module.exports (app.js:38854)
at Module../node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css (app.js:38769)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:100988)
at Module../resources/js/theme/Vuetify.js (app.js:2356)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:100988)
at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:2139)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:100988)
```

This is an extremely annoying issue, as I've not found anything related to it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For anyone coming later on, the solution was to delete all loaders both locally and globally, and reinstall the loaders step by step and check after each install, which one was doing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to remove `style-loader` and only use `css-loader` to get this error go.

```
yarn remove style-loader
```

Comment: Exactly, I've posted the comment to let future searchers, got overloaded with many issues that I forgot to update it. Thanks! I'll mark this answer.